# Avoid RuntimeError with circle reference

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following code:

```
class Cell(object):
    def eval(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class RefCell(Cell):
    def __init__(self, cell=None):
        self.next_cell = cell

    def set_next(self, cell):
        self.next_cell = cell
        if self.next_cell:
            try:
                check = self.next_cell.eval()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            else:
                if check == self:
                    raise Exception

    def eval(self):
        return self.next_cell.eval()


c1 = RefCell()
c2 = RefCell()
c3 = RefCell()
c4 = RefCell()

c1.set_next(c2)
c2.set_next(c3)
c3.set_next(c4)
c4.set_next(c2)
```

I'm trying to avoid the RuntimeError I'm encountering when:

```
c4.set_next(c2)
```

But I just can't figure out the way I can capture the circle reference and throw my generic exception, instead I'm running into this:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I would appreciate any idea.

Comment: What's the idea behind the `eval`? You could prolly pass the root parent as an argument to it and raise your exception when `self == parent`

Comment: As soon as control flow enters the `eval` method of `RefCell`, there's no way out. Are you trying to detect circular references?

Comment: @Jasper exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a history of nodes processed with subsequent calls to eval and check if you've visited a node before processing it.

```
def eval(self, history=None):
    if history and self in history:
        raise Exception
    # put eval logic here
    history = history or {}
    history.add(self)
    self.next_cell.eval(history)
```

Comment: This seems pretty pythonic.

Comment: I thought of this way but I thought better to avoid it in order to avoid passing the list to each eval, also this means the eval signature of RefCell doesn't match the eval signature of Cell. any ideas to improve upon this solution?

Comment: Passing "the list" is cheap, it is not copied for each call. Also, different signatures for overloaded methods don't seem too bad for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could introduce an attribute that defaults to False bit is set to true if a cells eval() function has been called. And then have the eval function raise the exception:

```
def eval(self):
    self.evaluated=True
    if self.next_cell.evaluated:
        raise Exception
    return self.next_cell.eval()
```

I havent tried it but it should work i think. Also im not sure if that return statement is needed as i dont know what should happen in your script later on.

Of course you would need to reset that attribute the next time you are trying to evaluate... Thats a little inconvenient.